# Solspace Importer not set up correctly?

Tags: ee, solspace-importer

I've taken over an EE project on which Importer has already been installed but not used yet (there are no Profiles set).

If I try to set up a profile, even though I have the correct ftp details for the file I get an Ajax error: AJAX Request was not successful. I know the ftp details are correct as I can connect via Filezilla using the same credentials.

If I ignore that failure and 'Continue' I get some PHP errors. The first is a warning:

Message: require_once(/mnt/www/xyz.co.uk/system/codeigniter/system/libraries/FTP.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: libraries/Solspace_ftp.php

Line Number: 16

The second is an error:

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/mnt/www/xyz.co.uk/system/codeigniter/system/libraries/FTP.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /mnt/www/xyz.co.uk/system/expressionengine/third_party/importer/libraries/Solspace_ftp.php on line 16

Has the module been set up incorrectly? Or am I missing something obvious?

Many thanks - Jon

Comment: We have received your email and have responded back to you now :)

Answer (score 1):

Your errors are saying that files are missing so it's safe to deduce that something isn't set up correctly. I suggest redownloading the files from your Solspace account and reuploading them to your server to test your theory.